# Environment variables .env not working in component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks

I'm new to google maps and .env Environment variables I have this component that is rendering google maps I'm trying to set the Environment variable instead of embedding the google maps API key directly, but it's not showing up. here is my code...

```
import React from "react"
import {GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker} from "@react-google-maps/api"

const MapContainer = () => {

    const mapStyles = {
        height: "50vh",
        width: "100%"
    }

    const defaultCenter = {
        lat: 40.668259, lng: -73.949158
    }


    const locations = [
        {
            name: "Brooklyn, NY",
            location: {
                lat: 40.668259,
                lng: -73.949158
            }
        }
    ]

    return (
        <LoadScript
            googleMapsApiKey={`${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}`}>
            <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
                zoom={13}
                center={defaultCenter}>
                {
                    locations.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <Marker key={item.name} position={item.location}/>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
    )
}

export default MapContainer
```

Could somone please help me.

Comment: Some questions: how are you assigning the env variables, in the CLI or in a `.env` file? Please provide that (with fake values). Is this a `create-react-app` project, or some other starting point for your project? If you `console.log(process.env)` what do you get? And finally, have you tried everything in the answer here:? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663555/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-the-front-end

Comment: It's in a .env file in the root.   `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY = dededededded`

Comment: Wha do you get if you `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY)` in your component?

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: @shlomo minkowicz Have you restarted your project since you added the env variable?

Comment: Yes I did and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Mine wasn't working either then I read the Alexei Darmin's suggestions and went to the mentioned Stackoverflow link. All it took was reading a few words at the bottom of one of the answers...run npm start after adding the .env file...yup... that did the trick.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).