# Adding POM version number to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, pom.xml

I have a POM file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.capgemini.jira.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-service</artifactId>
    <version> ${POM_JIRAVERSION}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I've got an HTML page where I want to display my POM version number, my version number is dynamic as you can see and changes with every build I make on Jenkins. How can retrieve the version from the Pom.xml and display it on my HTML ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Cmarkham Added it thanks

Comment: You could access and pass it as an environment variable, read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663555/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-the-front-end

Comment: Keep in mind that you want to access the POM version (backend) in your HTML/JS (frontend). You need a solution that bridges this gap, e.g. with a build tool like webpack for injecting environment variables.

Comment: Alternatively, you could implement a `GET` request in your Java backend, which returns the current version. You would query this method in your frontend JS then and display it.