# Access environment variable set up in circleci project in the application

Tags: reactjs, node.js, environment-variables, circleci

I have set up an environment variable in the circle ci project like [this](https://circleci.com/docs/set-environment-variable/#set-an-environment-variable-in-a-project). I am trying to access it in a js file. So I exported the variable in circle ci yaml file like this:

```
    jobs:
      build:
        ...
        steps:
          - run: 
              command: |
              echo 'export ENV_VAR="$ENV_VAR"' >> "$BASH_ENV"
                source "$BASH_ENV"
```

And I am trying to access in a js file as `process.env.ENV_VAR` but I am getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All custom variables you need to access in a js file should be named with the prefix REACT_APP_
For more info, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663555/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-the-front-end) can be referred to.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting that env only for that step. That env will be lost once this step is finished and the next steps won't be able to access it. Based on your use case you should configure the env, the doc has mentioned the support for project level, job level and even container level. Prefer Project level if possible, it's easy to set up.

Comment: I did set up the env variable in the project level. You can see that I have mentioned it in the first sentence